# How to manipulate event bubbling when registering click event upon a layer in mapbox gl js

Tags: javascript, events, mapbox-gl-js

How can I stop event propagation on layer click events?

```js
mapBox.on('click', layerId, function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    // e.stopPropagation(); which is not working 
    // e.originalEvent.stopPropagation(); which is not working 
    var popupHtml = getPopupHtmlWrapper(e.features[0]);
    new mapboxgl.Popup({closeButton:false})
        .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
        .setHTML(popupHtml)
        .addTo(mapBox);
});
```

Comment: what are you trying to stop the event from bubbling to?

Comment: @mollymerp I have tried setting up cancelBubble property to true, also the stopPropagation method but no success (both upon e.originalEvent object I am getting from callback)

Answer (score 14):

Mapbox provides access to the original event. Which means whenever we want to limit a `click` to the topmost layer clicked only, all we need to do is call `e.originalEvent.preventDefault()` on the first layer and check for `e.originalEvent.defaultPrevented` in the layers beneath:

```js
this.map
  .on('click', 'layer_1', function(e) { // topmost layer
    e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    // layer_1 functionality
  })
  .on('click', 'layer_2', function(e) { // second topmost layer
    if(!e.originalEvent.defaultPrevented) {
      // click was performed outside of layer_1
      e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
      // layer_2 exclusive functionality
    }
  })
  .on('click', 'layer_3', function(e) {
    if(!e.originalEvent.defaultPrevented) {
      // click was performed outside of layer_1 and layer_2
      e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
      // layer_3 exclusive functionality here...
    }
...
  })
```

Comment: You don't actually need to do it differently for the first event. `e.originalEvent.defaultPrevented` will default to `false` until you call `e.originalEvent.preventDefault()` so the inside of the if statement will execute even if it's the first event listener. So you can for example, assign these listeners in a loop and just do it the same way for all of them. The first doesn't need to be a special case.

Comment: it depends on the exact order in which you assigned event handlers. If you handle click from two different places - one that was assigned last can be used to check for `defaultPrevented`. Otherwise it'll always be false, because you can't catch if it's preventing default after another one was already fired.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe we don't need a global variable, I got the same problems as you, and I fixed it with the solution:

```js
mapbox.on('click', 'layer1', function(e){  
   e.originalEvent.cancelBubble = true;
   /*
    //or you can add an attr
    e['bubble'] = 'no';
   
   */
   console.log('layer1');

}
mapbox.on('click', 'layer2', function(e){  
   if(e.originalEvent.cancelBubble){
     return;
   }
   /*
     if(e['bubble] && e['bubble'] == 'no'){
       return;
     }   
   */
   console.log('layer2');
}
```

Comment: Why is that `if(e.originalEvent.cancelBubble){...` `true`, when you overwrite `e` in your function body with `mapbox.on('click', 'layer2', function(e){`?

Comment: Just FYI according to MDN "the cancelBubble property of the Event interface is a historical alias to Event.stopPropagation()". (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelBubble)

Answer (score 5):

Per the suggestion by @Stophface, I used

```
e => {
  const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point)
  if (features[0].layer.id === myLayerName ) {
    doMyClickAction(e)
  }
}
```

so as to only do something with the event when the layer I care about in this instance is the first one that is clicked.

Comment: Another slightly different option -      const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['top-layer'] })
      if (!features.length) {
        return
      }

Answer (score 3):

Was looking to find the same solution, but sharing event between the map and layer, so if layer, for example, was not clicked, I would like map click listener to be invoked, and opposite, if layer was clicked, I would like map click listener to be skipped

So I've ended up with the folowing:

```js
// Event handler for layer
function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  // handle layer event
}

// Event handler for map
function(e) {
  if(e.defaultPrevented) return
  // handle map event
}
```

So, prevent default is working but you should check for `defaultPrevented` property in event and handle it.

Comment: This seems as having the best balance between elegant and easy :D

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to save the event coordinates of the click on the layer and then compare these coordinates with the underlying layer and its event coordinates.

```
let clickCoords = {};

this.map.on('click', 'points', event => {
  clickCoords = event.point;
  console.log('Layer click')
});

Now, detect a click on the map, not on the points layer

this.map.on('click', () => {
  // check if coords are different, if they are different, execute whatever you need
  if (clickCoords.x !== event.point.x && clickCoords.y !== event.point.y) {
    console.log('Basemap click');
    clickCoords = {};
  }
});
```

Or, even better, use [queryRenderedFeatures()](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#queryrenderedfeatures).

```
this.map.on('click', event => {
   if (this.map.queryRenderedFeatures(event.point).filter(feature => feature.source === YOURLAYERNAME).length === 0) {
    console.log('Basemap click');
  }
});
```

Here is a [Mapbox example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any simple way of handling this. I am assuming you are trying to prevent the click event from propagating to an other layer. What you can do is using a global variable storing that a click just happened at those coordinates. Then in your other click handler you check this case.

```js
var recentClicks = {layer1 : null}

mapBox.on('click', "layer1", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    recentClicks["layer1"] = e.lngLat
    // Proceed to creating pop-up
});

mapBox.on('click', "layer2", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    if(recentClicks["layer1"] && recentClicks["layer1"][0] == e.lngLat[0] && recentClicks["layer1"][1] == e.lngLat[1]){
        recentClicks["layer1"] = null
        return
    } else {
      // Proceed to treating layer 2 click event
    }
});
```

With a bit of work, you can apply this to an infinite number of layers.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the above suggestions worked after I adjusted my layer ordering by setting the `beforeLayer` parameter when adding a layer:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-layer-in-stack/

If none of the above suggestions work for you, try playing with the layer order and going through them again.

Answer (score 0):

I created an add-on that allows you to stop the propagation(with immediatePropagation support) of events between layers. [Try this lib](https://github.com/marucjmar/any-routing/tree/master/packages/maplibre-layers-event-propagator)